# Can an application built with node and @angular/cli run offline?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I am new to `angular/cli` and `node`. I want to build an application using angular and deploy it to an environment that has all outside communication blocked via. firewall. You cannot even access any search engine. The db and everything required available in the intranet.

So my question is if I build the application using `ng new` and install dependencies using `npm install xxxxx`, build the `dist` in my development pc,   can I run it offline?

I plan to use `mdbootstrap`, `chartjs` and I have all my fonts for offline usage.

Anybody faced anything similar?

Comment: nearly everybody faces this situation. Why shouldn't it work?

Comment: @smnbbrv I did not know that. So i thought of asking here. Because before i was using some google libs and it didnt work offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for asking, but why don't you just try if it works? And to answer your question, yes you can. It only depends on your application if it needs to go outside your intranet. If it doesn't request any API, resource etc... not reachable from inside your intranet, then you are good to go.

Just updating dependencies need an internet connection

Comment: I don't want to build the application first and then know it does not work. So i thought of asking here, if someone faced anything similar in the past.

Comment: Also i will be building the app in my personal pc. Only the deployment environment is restricted.

Comment: @Raj one way to test that is to build the application, and disconnect your PC from the internet :) but rest assured, the angular-cli does not need internet to function

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Mainly i was skeptical because some of the google libs i used in the past didnt work offline.